Cannot login: kded5 request to open wallet - ksmserver closed - system unresponsive except of mouse movement
Since yesterday I cannot login any more. When I start, everything works until I have entered my credentials and kde has started to run ("kde", rotating wheel).
Then a popup comes in, "kded5 has requested to open the wallet kdewallet. .."
(Password doesn't work.)
Next, another popup underneath, "We are sorry, ksmserver closed unexpectedly. You cannot report ..."
Then, only the mouse cursor can still be moved on a black screen, no menu, nothing, and no reaction on keyboard events. Only a hard reset beings me back to boot. Then the same things happens once again ...
Unfortunately, I have no access to the grub menu, due to another, reported, accepted, but as yet unresolved bug.
Does anyone have an idea what to do, how I could enter the system, at least to obtain a terminal? I'm on 22.04.
